# Selberg zeta function analytic expressions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, riemann-surfaces, zeta-functions, algebraic-equations

Consider the following algebraic equation,
$$
y^n=\frac{(z-z_1)(z-z_3)}{(z-z_2)(z-z_4)}
$$
which is a Riemann surface of genus $n-1$ (after compactifying). The classical retrosection theorem due to Koebe states that every compact Riemann surface can be represented as a quotient, $\Omega/\Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is a Schottky group (which is a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$) with region of discontinuity $\Omega$. I am trying to evaluate the following sum,
$$
\log Z=-\sum_{\gamma\in \text{prim}}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\log|1-q_{\gamma}^m|
$$
where the sum is over all the primitive conjugacy classes of $\Sigma$ and the two eigenvalues of $\gamma$ are $q_{\gamma}^{\pm\frac{1}{2}}$ with $|q_{\gamma}|<1$. This sum looks similar to the Selberg zeta function but there the sum is usually over a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Is there any way to obtain this sum analytically, or at least to first order in $n-1$? I know there is an expansion of this sum in powers of $x=\frac{(z_3-z_2)(z_4-z_1)}{(z_3-z_1)(z_4-z_2)}$, but I cannot find any exact expressions.

Comment: This question was posted here about an hour after the same question was posted on Math StackExchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235746/selberg-zeta-function-analytic-expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry is that not allowed? I just wanted more people to look at my question. If it's against the rules I'll delete my other post.

Comment: It's recommended you indicate in your question when you cross-post to avoid duplication of effort by those considering posting an answer to your question, and cross-posting immediately is generally discouraged (e.g. see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638).